# Which SE is suitable for asking a question about adblock?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My adblocker won't block an ad on Facebook. Should I put the question about it in webapps?

Comment: adblock isn't a web application, it's a browser extension/plugin. So webapps is surely not the correct place. Better just ask in the adblock support forums. (e.g. https://adblockplus.org/forum/)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry I use uBlock origin to be specific. Thanks

Comment: Still, this should be addressed to the author of the extension, no SE site can debug or fix third party browser extensions as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShadowWizard got it, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [some questions on using adblock software over on Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=Adblock).

Particular relevant, it seems asking questions on creating custom filters is permitted over there.

Of course, you might alternately consider contacting the developer of the extension, or the filter subscription author you think should block it.

First of all though, you probably want to check your current filter subscriptions are up-to-date.